# How to remove ios today extension from app

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, today-extension

I've added `today extension` to my app (for test only) and now, I want to remove it. I've tryed to delete all files that seemd to be connected with extension, but when I run app again, extension is still available in today notification view... Can anyone help me to remove that? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clean your project (`cmd + shift + k`) then run again.

Answer (score 3):

Five steps:
1. Delete the app from the device 
2. Delete the Extension target from the project 
3. Delete the share(or other extension) group from .xcodeproj 
4. cmd + shift + k 
5. removed the scheme-build and from Manage Schemes

Then just run,everything is OK(Have tried by myself)

Answer (score 2):

Clean your project and delete the app from the simulator (and from the device)

Answer (score 0):

Three steps:
1. Delete the app from the device
2. Delete the Extension target from the project
3. Reinstall the application, and the today extension will not be installed

I tried the following one at a time, using xCode 6.1.1, with no avail:
1) Clean (Shift + Cmd + K), deploy to iPad
2) Delete app, Clean, deploy to iPad
3) Delete app and derived data, Clean, deploy to iPad

What finally worked for me is deleting the App, then deleting the Extension target before reinstalling.

You should probably also do the following:
1) Go into capabilities of your primary target, and disable groups, if it was enabled only for the today extension. This will remove the associated entry from the com.apple.security.application-groups array of your entitlements file.

2) If you aren't using App Groups anymore, then you should probably also comment out any code that instantiated NSUserDefaults with initWithSuiteName, if it was used for implementing the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Share Extension.
I removed the extension from the Target, deleted the folder of the extension, removed the scheme-build and from Manage Schemes and still I got the extension in the UIActivityViewController.
I cleaned the product and it still showed.
I cleaned the product a few more times and then finally it was gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove the TARGET-....extension completely from my iOS project. To do that, remember to click on "Show/Hide projec and target" on XCode and then click the "-" button on target.

[image]